# Adjusting CoordinatorLayout behavior

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

Let's assume that we have the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In this layout, if I drag the `SearchView` upward, it will collapse and disappear. But I wonder how I can attach this dragging effect to my `RecyclerView`. Means I like to collapse the `SearchView` whenever I scroll `RecyclerView` items upward, but expand `SearchView` when I scroll `RecylcerView` items downward. Do I need to create a custom behavior for `SearchView` or it is possible to create this effect by available behaviors?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a **collapsing toolbar layout** and  wrap up the **searchView** inside it... and also wrap up the **recyclerView** with a **nestedScrollView** and add the `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>` to the nested scroll view instead

Dont forget to add  `scrollFlags` and `content_scrim` to your collapsing toolbar layout..

The collapsing toolbar layout should be inside the `appBarLayout`

For reference check this out

https://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/

Comment: it seems `CollapsingToolbar` is not needed. I got required effect with adding `NestScrollView` only.

Comment: you can do both ways @Afshin

Answer (score 0):

The only change you have to make is to add `|enterAlways` to your existing `app:layout_scrollFlags` attribute.

Comment: you mean after adding `NestedScrollView`, isn't it? Because it seems without it, `|enterAlways`will not be sufficient.

Comment: @Afshin no, I do not. `RecyclerView` is a fully-functional scrolling sibling for the purposes of `AppBarLayout`.

Comment: @Afshin unless you've left something out of your posted code. If I copy/paste the layout you posted and attach an adapter + layout manager to the `RecyclerView`, I get the correct collapsing behavior with no (further) modifications.

Comment: it is strange. it is not working like this for me. But I should say that I have **not** assigned adapter+layout manager, because I was just working with layout itself and I didn't think that I need to assign those two for getting collapsing behavior. I will test it after assigning those two.